# Trying to get a qualifier to work, not sure what's wrong

Tags: wikidata, sparql, ontology

I'm trying to get total assets for companies within the US, but I only want assets from the most recent year available in Wikidata. I'm using P2403 to get total assets and I'm trying to use the qualifier P585, but I'm not getting results.

```
 SELECT distinct ?company ?companyLabel ?founding ?founder ?founderLabel ?CEO ?CEOLabel ?employeeCount ?time
WHERE 
{
  ?company wdt:P31 wd:Q6881511 .
  ?company wdt:P17 wd:Q30.
  OPTIONAL {?company wdt:P571 ?founding.}
  OPTIONAL {?company wdt:P112 ?founder.}
  OPTIONAL {?company wdt:P169 ?CEO .}
  OPTIONAL {?company wdt:P1128 ?employeeCount.}
  OPTIONAL {?company wdt:P2403 ?totalAssets.}
  OPTIONAL {?totalAssets wdt:P585 ?time}
  OPTIONAL {?company wdt:P2137 ?totalEquity.}
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use something like:

```
OPTIONAL { ?company p:P2403 ?statement . 
           ?statement ps:P2403 ?totalAssets.
OPTIONAL { ?statement pq:P585 ?time} }
```

The first change is to get the *statement* for p2403, and then get both the main value and qualifier value from that statement. Note the ps (main value) and pq (qualifier) syntax.

The second is to reorder the OPTIONAL clauses so you only go looking for a qualifier value if there's a main statement - otherwise this will send it off on a wild goose chase and time out.